# Pass value to broadcast receiver, putExtra in loop,

Tags: android

**In short:** I have a BroadcastReceiver that listens for SMS delivery receipts. The onReceive is called, but how can I identify which SMS the receipt is about?
Putting values in the Intent didn't work because if I send three SMS at the same time, I will have each time the last SMS identifier (putExtra() seems to override values with same key)

**Details:**

I have a class that listens to GCM push notifications (`MyGcmListenerService`). One method will parse the JSON data from the server; data includes an array of IDs, text messages and numbers, e.g.:

> {"texts":[{"id":"11","number":"0494587693","text":"hello"},{"id":"12","number":"0494635478","text":"world"},{"id":"13","number":"0487533693","text":"foo"}]}

For each text message, the method will launch an IntentService (`SendSmsService`) that will send the SMS. See code below:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(stringResponse);
JSONArray texts = object.getJSONArray("texts");

for (int i = 0; i < texts.length(); ++i) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = texts.getJSONObject(i);
    int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
    String number = jsonObject.getString("number");
    String text = jsonObject.getString("text");

    Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, SendSmsService.class);
    startService(mServiceIntent);
}
```

Code to send the SMS in `SendSmsService`:

```
Intent sentIntent = new Intent("com.example.smsgateway.SMS_SENT");
PendingIntent sentPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        getApplicationContext(), 0, sentIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Intent deliveryIntent = new Intent("com.example.smsgateway.SMS_DELIVERED");
PendingIntent deliverPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        getApplicationContext(), 0, deliveryIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
manager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, sentPendingIntent, deliverPendingIntent);
```

**The problem** is that I have a class which listens for delivery receipts, and that class needs to identify the id (from json string above) that the delivery receipt is about.

```
public class SmsDeliveredReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SMS delivered"); // OK, but which one??
```

I have tried to pass the ID in the Intent object (putExtra):
From `MyGcmListenerService` to `SendSmsService`:

```
mServiceIntent .putExtra(SendSmsService.EXTRA_ID, id);
```

From `SendSmsService` for the receiver:

```
deliveryIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, id);
```

But quickly I realize that I get only the last IDs from the loop. The putExtra() overrides the other IDs because of the unique key I guess.

I can't think of a solution for this problem, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem via IRC #android-dev

The answer can be found in the docs:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

> A common mistake people make is to create multiple PendingIntent
>   objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents,
>   expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time. This does not
>   happen. The parts of the Intent that are used for matching are the
>   same ones defined by Intent.filterEquals. If you use two Intent
>   objects that are equivalent as per Intent.filterEquals, then you will
>   get the same PendingIntent for both of them.
>
> There are two typical ways to deal with this.
>
> If you truly need multiple distinct PendingIntent objects active at
>   the same time (such as to use as two notifications that are both shown
>   at the same time), then you will need to ensure there is something
>   that is different about them to associate them with different
>   PendingIntents. This may be any of the Intent attributes considered by
>   Intent.filterEquals, or different request code integers supplied to
>   getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int), getActivities(Context, int,
>   Intent[], int), getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int), or
>   getService(Context, int, Intent, int).

I used a unique requestCode

Answer (score 1):

You need a Request Code as you see on getBroadcast I add RowId.intValue() this is because I want to receive that unique request. this way they do not get overwritten. This way you prevent the same values in your loop getting missed.

also take notice of PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT this means that. the broadcast will notify once. This prevents undesired duplicate loops.

```
String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    Intent intentSent = new Intent(SENT);
    intentSent.putExtra("RowId", RowId);

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, RowId.intValue(), intentSent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
    Intent intentDelivered = new Intent(DELIVERED);
    intentDelivered.putExtra("RowId", RowId);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, RowId.intValue(), intentDelivered, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    try {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI); //deliveredPI
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception " + e.getMessage());
    }
```